# How to get a dictionary of dictionary properties values?

Tags: c#, dictionary, properties

I have this:

```
public class GraphicsDraw
{
    public Dictionary<int,GraphicItem> items { get; set; }
}
public abstract class GraphicItem
{
    public float ItemSize { get; set; }
}
```

And I can access to all ItemSize's like this:

```
{
    GraphicsDraw gd = new GraphicsDraw();
    gd.items[i].ItemSize;
}
```

Is there any nice way that I can list ItemSize's down separately in another dictionary whit same key and ItemSize values?

```
Dictionary<int, float> ItemSize = items.(???)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, using `ToDictionary`:

```
items.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.ItemSize);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do, which uses LINQ,

```
Dictionary<int,float> itemSizes = 
    items.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value.ItemSize);
```

The `ToDictionary` accepts two delegates (or lambda expressions), the first one to select the key and the second one to select the value of the dictionary.

In your case you want to keep the same key, but change the value to the `ItemSize` property, thus the second expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use LINQ to extract necessary keys and values from items property.

```
items.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ItemSize);
```

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is only code. Would you mind expanding it with some text explaining how it works / how it solves the problem?